# kendo ui mobile listview endless scroll displaying only one item

Tags: javascript, css, listview, kendo-ui

I'm using kendo ui mobile listview. Everything is ok as long as I don't set endlessScoll or loadMore to true. With the EndlessScroll the listview display only the first Item.

In the chrome inspector, the UL tag has 37px height but when i change it to 400px or more it shows the others items.

Where am i wrong ?

```
      $("#myListview").kendoMobileListView({
        dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: function (options) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'Get',
                        url: url,
                        success: function (result) {
                            options.success(result);
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            options.error(result);
                        },
                        crossDomain: true
                    })
                }
            },
            schema: {
                total: function () { return myCount }
            },
            serverPaging: true,
            serverSorting: true,
            pageSize: 20
            }),
        template: $("#myListview_template").text(),
        appendOnRefresh:true,
        endlessScroll: true,//listworks fine when false or by default
        style: "inset",               
        click: function (e) { console.log(e.dataItem);},
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The listview widget is not compatbile with `style:inset` in endlessScroll mode thanks to [kendo](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile/listview/overview#press-to-load-more--endless-scrolling).
Enabling endless scrolling or press to load more options triggers the virtual mode of the ListView.
Currently, certain features (grouped mode and inset styling) are not supported in virtual mode.